# In WiX, is it possible to update the status text while the features are being installed

Tags: wix

While the features are being installed, is it possible to show a custom message in the progress bar. I am aware of ProgressText, but it only works for CustomActions.

```
<ProgressText Action="MyCA">Running My CA</ProgressText>
```